# Can I access the API of apps compatible with OneLogin using the OneLogin API?

Tags: onelogin

I work for an Managed Service Provider and we have a variety of web tools, many of which are compatible with OneLogin.  The truth is, that the tools we have are great.  But we waste a lot of time jumping between them.  The big two are IT Glue and Autotask.  Autotask is a ticketing tools and IT Glue is a network documentation tool.  If we are working on a ticket, we first have to lookup the the ticket in AT, them jump to IT Glue and pull a password for example.  Autotask itself can be frustrating at times to navigate, not that its hard, just time consuming.  So I'm panning a web app to simplify the UI a little and implement some custom ticket sorting algorithms to prioritize certain types of tickets.  At the same time, I'm going to be tying into the IT Glue API and include it in the new UI.

It would be really nice if I could tie into these API's via OneLogin.  If nothing else, it would be nice If I could query credentials for the apps assigned to a user so that I can use their information to log them into each API.  Is any of this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can list the apps a user have access to (https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/get-apps-for-user) pretty much the same as (https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/embed-apps/get-apps-to-embed-for-a-user) and allow them to login from your site leveraging Desktop SSO. If the apps are not SAML ready but username/pwd your users will need to have the browser plugin installed.

Comment: Ok.  I guess the idea is that I don't want to launch the actual websites. I want to access the API's using their own credentials (this way, I don't have to query if they have permissions for whatever action they need to perform).

Comment: Then you will only need to call the get apps for user. The result will list all the apps assigned to the roles the user has been assigned to.

Comment: Yeah, but at that point why use the onelogin api?  I can query the roles in the Autotask API and permissions in the IT Glue API just as easily and I plan on using their API's anyways.  Which makes using the onelogin API nothing more than added complexity.

It's unfortunate, I was really excited by the possibility of being able to tie into multiple API's from one source.  Do you know if anything like this is planned?